# Returning Factorials greater than 12 in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, int, biginteger, factorial, nsuinteger

I have the following code, and I want it to give me factorial values up to 20.

```
-(NSUInteger)factorialofNumber(NSUInteger n){
static NSUInteger f[N + 1];
static NSUInteger i = 0;
if (i == 0)
{
    f[0] = 1;
    i = 1;
}
while (i <= n)
{
    f[i] = i * f[i - 1];
    i++;
}
return f[n];
}
```

The issue is that when this executes, all values above 12 are incorrect. I have placed this in my prefix file to try and have larger values available but it hasn't fixed the problem. Any hints to work around this?

```
#define NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64 1
```

Comment: Lookup "overflow". Use a datatype that can hold larger values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factorial of 13 is bigger than 32 bit unsigned integer. 
Instead of NSUInteger you could use `unsigned long long` or `uint64_t`. This way you always get 64 bit values and keep binary compatibility, which might suffer with `NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64` declared. [64-Bit Transition Guide for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/64BitChangesCocoa/64BitChangesCocoa.html):

> The NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64 macro is useful when binary compatibility is not a concern, such as when building an application.